# Pathauto insert taxonomy term custom url

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have change the url of an taxonomy term. Now when i use a field with taxonomy term the url is showing like this:

```
[node:field-taxonomy:parents:join-path]/[node:field-taxonomy:name]/[node:title]
```

**auto/safety-tools/audi**

The taxonomy term has name **Safety Tools** but i have change the url to just **tools**.

like **auto/tools/audi**

How i can load to my node the custom term url path.

I tried [node:field-taxonomy:url],[node:field-taxonomy:url:absolute],[node:field-taxonomy:url:relative] without success

Comment: Did you mean you have not bulked-updated your url aliases via Pathauto? When you make changes to aliases you should update the URIs right?

Comment: well i'm not sure what you mean. I haven't mass update the urls from pathauto just change the url of a taxonomy term. Even if i have used mass update(i realy don't have ever see) when new products will created the url will still have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern:

```
[node:field-taxonomy:parents:join-path]/tools/[node:title]
```

(manually set the middle part of the pattern).

Or, if you have several terms (not just Safety Tools), you can use

```
[node:field-taxonomy:parents:join-path]/[node:field-taxonomy:url:path]/[node:title]
```

([node:field-taxonomy:url:path] is the path component of the term's URL)